# Windows 7 BSoD - KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR

Tags: windows-7, crash, bsod

I got a random BSoD while using my laptop today. I haven't had a BSoD in months, and the issue hasn't repeated so far (it happened around 12:17 UTC).

```
KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR
*** STOP: 0x0000007A (0xFFFFF6FC400099E8, 0xFFFFFFFFCC000000E, 0x00000000B28CB860, 0xFFFFF880013D270)
*** Ntfs.sys - Address FFFFF88000133D270 base at FFFFF8800124B000, DateStamp 5167f5fc
```

Comment: have you tried to diagnose your hdd? since it fails on ntfs.sys, it could be a hdd failure

Comment: I've just run CHKDSK in read-only mode and it has found some errors. I'll run `chkdsk /f /r C:`.

Comment: I'd also suggest running [MemTest86](http://www.memtest86.com) to verify that it wasn't bad ram allocation/usage/errors.  But before doing those, make a backup of your important stuff if you are able to.

Comment: CHKDSK has fixed some file system errors. I'm going to run MemTest86 now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error code 0xC000000E means STATUS_NO_SUCH_DEVICE.

```
C:\Users\André>err 0xC000000E
# for hex 0xc000000e / decimal -1073741810
  STATUS_NO_SUCH_DEVICE                                          ntstatus.h
# A device which does not exist was specified.
# as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), FACILITY_NULL (0x0), Code 0xe
# for hex 0xe / decimal 14
  ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY                                              winerror.h
# Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.
# 2 matches found for "0xC000000E"
```

You should open the Laptop, remove the HDD and insert the HDD again. This often fixes issues with HDDs in laptops.

Comment: I haven't got the error since then, but I might try that if it appears again. Thanks! I'd +1 if I had enough reputation to do so. :P

Comment: nice to hear that this trick fixed it :)